# How to stop zsh from printing out command

Tags: raspberry-pi, zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

just setup zsh with oh-my-zsh on Raspberry Pi

After every command, it reprints the command I typed. For example...

```
pi@raspberrypi ~>> ls

;lsDesktop ocr_pi.png python_games
```

Comment: Is this on the console or in a terminal emulator?

Comment: Does `alias ls` output anything?

Comment: @chepner yes, ls --color=auto. But it happens for every command, even ;zsh when I first login.

Answer (score 0):

Two causes of stuff like this are:

1. (most likely) You have something in a command execution hook causing this. See this for details http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Hook-Functions

try

```
which precmd
which preexec
which zshaddhistory
```

or if they did it using the arrays to hold hooks:

```
echo $precmd_functions
echo $preexec_functions
echo $zshaddhistory_functions
```

or any of the hooks described in that page with '_functions' appended to it.

There is likely some buggy function bound to get executed right before you run a command or when you save your history etc. To turn them off (other than fixing oh-my-zsh or your setup of it) Call `unset precmd_functions` to unset an array of functions, or `unfunction precmd`.

2. (very unlikely) you may have something funny getting executed in your prompt (unlikely but possible). Try `export PROMPT='foo '` or unsetting PS1.